# Android studio compatiblity

Tags: android-studio

Android studio 2.2 was installed, SDK correctly installed,OS windows7 32 bit, build new project OK, can't start first program with error message:

Details:

Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by installing android studio on windows 64bit and it works properly.